# in google tv, QSB only show results custom data at 'other' tab?

Tags: android, google-tv, android-qsb

I made two custom content provider and confirmed, in nexus 7 version 4.3 to show results at different tabs. also I compiled with API 17.

And then I deployed to Google TV, but it show different view. in Google TV, showing only one result and all results displayed Others tab.

if i want to make custom result tabs with each content providers and show all results at custom tab.

what is different in Google TV?

Comment: I'm assuming that this is a custom search provider?  If so, Google TV limits it to one result currently, which is unfortunate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google TV is currently on API 13 (Honeycomb) - once Jellybean comes to Google TV (soon) it should work as you expect.